# Old Greek vs ancient Greek

Tags: dictionaries

I learned the language of Plato and Sokrates at school - is it 'old Greek' or 'ancient Greek'?

Comment: It's Greek to me...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Greek not English. The only connection to English is that it was written in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a general audience, the language of Plato is *ancient Greek*, as distinguished from the Greek of the prehistoric, medieval, and modern epochs.

To be more specific, you can call it *classical Greek*, which refers to ancient Greek as spoken during the classical era of the 5th and 4th centuries, as opposed to the *archaic Greek* that preceded it and the *Hellenistic* or *Koine* Greek that followed.

For the benefit of the philologically inclined, you can further narrow to *Attic Greek* (or *classical Attic*), the language Plato would have used as an aristocrat from Attica.

The term *Old Greek* does seem to exist, but to refer to what I know as *Medieval Greek* (or *Byzantine Greek*).

Comment: Homer is in Archaic Greek (usually called 'Homeric', about -900), Plato and Aristotle are in Classical Greek (about -400; Attic dialect -- there were a **lot** of dialects), and the New Testament was in Koiné or Hellenistic (post-Alexander, >-200) Greek, which was the common language of the Eastern Mediterranean for more than a millennium.

Answer (score 1):

It's *Ancient Greek*, but, inconsistently, *Old English* and *Old Norse*.

Comment: Because the people that assigned the epithet "Classic" did not believe that it could possibly apply to English or Norse. Or, in fact anything but Latin, Greek, and (grudgingly) Hebrew or Sanskrit.

Comment: _Classical English_ might be misleading. What is now called Old English was once known as Anglo-Saxon, and sometimes still is. Old English confirms the continuity of the language, while Anglo-Saxon emphasises the differences.